# Mismatch in Stats UI & Splunk API

Tags: splunk

```
index=<<My_index>> earliest="12/23/2020:10:00:00" latest="12/23/2020:11:00:00" "<<url>>" 
| eval MyFeild=replace(MyFeild,"\d{1}\d+","") 
| search MyFeild=*sample_search* 
| stats count by MyFeild
```

When I have been using the above search criteria in UI, it gives a table in Statistics tab with `MyFeild` and its total Count

When I am using the splunkapi for some reason I am not getting the consolidated output and I am trying to remove any numerical data in the URL

```
https://<<mydomain for my splunkapi>>/services/search/jobs/export?search=search index=<<My_index>>  earliest="12/23/2020:10:00:00" latest="12/23/2020:11:00:00" "<<URL>>" 
| eval MyFeild=replace(MyFeild,"\d{1}\d+","") 
| search MyFeild=*sample_search* 
| stats count by MyFeild
```

Not sure If I am missing anything here

Comment: You say you don't get the "consolidated output", but what *do* you get?  Why are you trying to remove numerical data from the URL?  Are you authenticating?  Please share the full API request.

Comment: You can simplify your `replace` thusly: `| eval MyFeild=replace(MyFeild,"\d{2,}","")`. That will match a minimum of 2 digits up to however many are in a row. Alternatively, you could also do this: `| eval MyFeild=replace(MyFeild,"\d\d+","")`. There's no reason to put the quantifier `{1}` after a character or character class in a regular expression: the regex engine will *always* match 1 of something *unless you tell it otherwise*.